# Correct way to loop through checkbox and delete all ticked categories with as few queries as possible?

Tags: php, laravel

Up until now, I had to click a delete button every time I wanted to delete a category. So if I wanted to delete 10 categories, I would've had to click a delete button 10 times. This is why I'm now trying to implement a checkbox and then just loop through the checked categories, however, I'm not sure if I'm doing it with as few queries as possible.

My checkbox looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('deleteCategories') }}">
     @foreach($categories as $category)
         <input type="checkbox" name="categories[]" value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}<br>
     @endforeach
     <button class='delete-btn' type="submit">Delete</button>
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     {{ method_field('delete') }}
</form>
```

And my deleteCategories() function looks like this so far:

```
public function deleteCategories(Request $request){

    if (!Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')) {
            return redirect()->back();
    } else if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')) {
        $categories = $request['categories'];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $categoryToDelete = Category::where('id', $category)->first();
            $categoryName = $categoryToDelete->image_file_name;
            $categoryToDelete->delete();
            Storage::delete('public/uploads/categories/'.$categoryName);
            Storage::delete('public/uploads/categories/thumbnails/'.$categoryName);
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

As you can see, for every $category in $categories, I run a query to find the category with that id and then I delete it from the database and local storage. That means if I've selected 4 checkboxes, I'd have to run 4 queries to find those specific categories and then delete them.

Is there a better way to accomplish this with less queries? I'm open to editing both HTML and PHP if it's gonna make it faster, more readable, more scalable, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `whereIn`:

```
Category::whereIn('id', $request->get('categories'))->delete();
```

**Note:** If you don't want the records permanently deleted make sure the `Category` model is setup to handle soft deletes.

Comment: I just checked what soft deleting is ( since I didn't know ) and I wonder in what case would I want to soft delete instead of straight up delete permanently from the database?

Comment: Ultimately its up to the requirements for your application.  An accidental deletion of a category could be one case. This way you can display your accidentally deleted categories to your user with a restore category option.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. So does whereIn take in more than one Ids and delete them at one fell swoop?

Comment: Don't I still need to makes queries so that I could get the image_file_name which is then used for the deletion of the files from local storage?

Comment: No, `whereIn` takes in an array of values, passing an array of category ids is sufficient to perform the delete.

Comment: Yes, the deletion from the database, however, later in the code I need the image_file_name for each of the deleted categories so I could delete them from the local storage as well.

Comment: That makes sense, you can retrieve the filename for the image by using the `withTrashed` syntax if you are soft deleting, or create another input field(hidden) and send the image name in your request.

Comment: Using hidden input field makes sense. Thanks.